# Print JFrame by splitting to multiple pages

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe, graphics2d

I want to print `JFrame` by breaking it into parts and printing each part on each page by zooming the part.

Suppose the `JFrame` is of size 100x100. Then I want to divide the `JFrame` into cells each of size 20*50. So I will be having 20 cells. I want to magnify or zoom the parts and print them each on different page.

Anybody having any ideas about how to do it?

Comment: "*Anybody having any ideas about how to do it?"*  Use Java.  For more specific answers, ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to adapt one of the approaches examined in [*Tutorials & Code Camps Chapter 6 Continued: Advanced Printing*](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/advprint.html#mp), which covers several related topics:

- Multiple Components Per Page
- Components Larger Than One Page
- Printing a `JTable` Component
- Printing a Sales Report